# Error when combining file and db upload in an ASP script

Tags: asp-classic, upload

The "pure ASP" file upload script I'm working with is giving me an error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'

Invalid procedure call or argument: 'MidB'
```

on this line (line 103 of include file clsUpload.asp):

```
mstrDelimiter = MidB(mbinData, 1, InStrB(1, mbinData, CRLF) - 1)
```

when I combine the File upload and the Database upload scripts on the same page. 
I thought it might have something to do with the instantiation of the class, and I've tried leaving the class established throughout the script, rather than setting it to 'nothing' and re establishing it, but that didn't make any difference.  Any ideas?

The upload scripts work fine, as long as they are on separate pages, posted to separately by the first two forms on the page (below).  The third form, however, isn't successful.
Much appreciated!

(Code in full below)

Note: the "clsUpload.asp" and "clsField.asp" files were too large to post. 
They are, however available here:
http://www.codeguru.com/dbfiles/get_file/upload_files_without_com_v2.zip?id=19297&lbl=UPLOAD_FILES_WITHOUT_COM_V2_ZIP

Form Page Below:

```
 <H2>To Database</H2>
<FORM name="a" id="a" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" action="ToDatabase.asp">
<INPUT type="File" name="File1">
<INPUT name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
 </FORM>

<H2>To File System</H2>
<FORM name="b" id="b" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" action="ToFileSystem.asp">
<INPUT type="File" name="File1">
<INPUT name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
</FORM>


<H2>To Both Database and File System</H2>
<FORM name="c" id="c" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" action="ToDatabaseAndFileSystem.asp">
<INPUT type="File" name="File1">
<INPUT name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
</FORM>


<HR>
<P>
This script provided to you by <A href="http://www.lewismoten.com">Lewis Moten</A>.
Please help me out and link back to my site from your own website, news groups,
postings on other websites, email, etc.
</P>

<p>Database file list below
</p>
<ol>
<%
Dim objUpload
Dim strFileName
Dim objConn
Dim objRs
Dim lngFileID


Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" &     Server.MapPath("Files.mdb")
objRs.Open "SELECT * FROM Files", objConn, 2, 2

If Not (objRs.EOF And objRs.BOF) Then
objRs.MoveFirst
Do Until objRs.EOF = True
strFileName=objRs.Fields("FileName").Value
lngFileID = objRs.Fields("FileID").Value
%>
<li><A href="DataFile.asp?FileID=<%=lngFileID%>"><%=strFileName%></A></li>
<br />
<%
    objRs.MoveNext
Loop
Else
response.write("MsgBox """ & "There are not records in the recordset." & """<"&"/script>")
End If



objRs.Close
Set objRs = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing
Set objUpload = Nothing
%>
</ol>
```

Form Processing Page (combined)

```vbs
 <!--#INCLUDE FILE="clsUpload.asp"-->
 <%
 Dim objUpload
 Dim strFileName
 Dim objConn
 Dim objRs
 Dim lngFileID
 Dim strPath


 '///database upload section - begin///
 ' Instantiate Upload Class
 Set objUpload = New clsUpload

 ' Grab the file name
 strFileName = objUpload.Fields("File1").FileName
 strLength = objUpload.Fields("File1").Length


 Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 ' Sometimes I personally have errors with one method on different servers, but the      other works.
 objConn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("Files.mdb")
 'objConn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("Files.mdb")

 'objRs.Open "Files", objConn, 3, 3
 objRs.Open "Files", objConn, 2, 2

 objRs.AddNew

 objRs.Fields("FileName").Value = objUpload.Fields("File1").FileName
 objRs.Fields("FileSize").Value = objUpload.Fields("File1").Length
 objRs.Fields("ContentType").Value = objUpload.Fields("File1").ContentType
 objRs.Fields("BinaryData").AppendChunk objUpload("File1").BLOB & ChrB(0)

 objRs.Update

 objRs.Close

 'objRs.Open "SELECT Max(FileID) AS ID FROM Files", objConn, 3, 3
 objRs.Open "SELECT Max(FileID) AS ID FROM Files", objConn, 2, 2
 lngFileID = objRs.Fields("ID").Value
 objRs.Close


 Set objRs = Nothing
 Set objConn = Nothing
 Set objUpload = Nothing
 %>
 File has been saved in database.<BR>
 <BR>
 View this file:<BR>
 <BR>
 <A href="DataFile.asp?FileID=<%=lngFileID%>"><%=strFileName%></A>

 '///database upload section - end///






 '///file server upload section - begin///
 <%
 ' Instantiate Upload Class
 Set objUpload = New clsUpload

 ' Grab the file name
 strFileName = objUpload.Fields("File1").FileName
 ' Compile path to save file to
 strPath = Server.MapPath("Uploads") & "\" & strFileName
 ' Save the binary data to the file system
 objUpload("File1").SaveAs strPath




 ' Release upload object from memory
 Set objUpload = Nothing

 MyVariable = strFileName
 Response.Write "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" & MyVariable & "');</script>"
 %>
 File has been saved in file system.<BR>
 <BR>
 View this file:<BR>
 <BR>
 <A href="Uploads\<%=strFileName%>">Uploads\<%=strFileName%></A>

 <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->


 '///file server upload section - begin///




 <ol>
 <%
 Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 objConn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("Files.mdb")
 objRs.Open "SELECT * FROM Files", objConn, 2, 2

 If Not (objRs.EOF And objRs.BOF) Then
objRs.MoveFirst
Do Until objRs.EOF = True
 strFileName=objRs.Fields("FileName").Value
 lngFileID = objRs.Fields("FileID").Value%>
 <li><A href="DataFile.asp?FileID=<%=lngFileID%>"><%=strFileName%></A></li>
 <br />
 <%
    objRs.MoveNext
Loop
 Else
MsgBox "There are not records in the recordset."
 End If



 objRs.Close
 Set objRs = Nothing
 Set objConn = Nothing
 Set objUpload = Nothing
 %>
 </ol>
```

Comment: Is the "Form Processing Page (combined)" the code of "ToDatabaseAndFileSystem.asp" file?

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the clsField.vbs file

If the path does not contain a "\" then the FileName field stays blank:

I would suggest adding an else condition to the if statement like so:

```
    ' Parse File Name
    If Not InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") = 0 Then
        FileName = Mid(pstrPath, InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") + 1)
    else
        FileName = pstrPath
    End If
```

Comment: I also think there is a newer version of the clsUpload class where this is either not a problem or is fixed: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8525&lngWId=4#zip

Comment: Is your `If` statement really necessary?  Since `FileName = Mid(pstrPath, 1)` is equivalent to `FileName = pstrPath` it seems superflous to me.

Comment: Yip, I agree you could replace the entire if block with the assignment of:  FileName = Mid(pstrPath, InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") + 1)

Comment: Thanks for your help in this.  I've added this code, and now I get the same error message on the same line.  As I have the file system upload and database upload script on the same page, would that in itself be causing the problem?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have been trying it, as well.  I get this error message with it when I combine the db with the file system save scripts.  The last script on the page throws the error.   This is the error: error '80040004'

Failed to save file: 2012_Jul_31-44924.66.bin. No data was found within the file (zero bytes).

Answer (score 0):

This line fails:

```
mstrDelimiter = MidB(mbinData, 1, InStrB(1, mbinData, CRLF) - 1)
```

Possible reasons:

- mbinData is zero length
- mbinData does not contain CRLF
- mbinData starts with CRLF
- the identifier CRLF does not contain the expected byte sequence

Discover which of the above is true in your case and you will find the problem.