# How do I enable image uploads in the self-hosted version of Tinymce for Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, tinymce

How do I enable image uploads for the self-hosted version of Tinymce 4 for Classic ASP?

The only hint that I have found for adding the editor is...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textearea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny!</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

By using this setup the only option for INSERT is a horizontal line, but I need to upload an image. I see the option in online examples, but how is that possible?

It needs to be self-hosted (not CDN) because it is for internal use and needs modification for additional security. PHP cannot be used here but I do have ASPupload if that can be used.

Some more useful documentation might help.

Comment: ASPUPLOAD is the way to go, but not sure how to make it work with tinymce, but seems like that is just an editor so won't matter at all?

Comment: Check over here at this question - the commerical uploader might be the penultimate solution as aspupload seemed to stop working properly for many people.  link -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678619/error-when-combining-file-and-db-upload-in-an-asp-script

Comment: I use ASPupload in other projects and never had problems. But the problem here is how to add the option of being able to upload from the editor's toolbar.

Comment: I had used it in other projects eons ago, but had ran into similar problems that other users have had with it in more modern times.  Not sure there is a easy button to click something on the toolbar, but you could use Notepad ++ and open the file and just paste the code you need in the pages you need them manually.

Comment: Most other online editors that support ASP already include ASPupload. But if Tinymce doesn't include it by default it may only mean that your config needs to call it after loading the appropriate plugin.

Comment: But that is the problem, there is absolutely nothing about this in any docs or from online search that I can find.

Comment: There is a solution but I am away from my office for a while. In the meantime, look at using CKeditor because we found that Tinymce lacks legacy browser support. You will have the same upload problem but the solution is the same. I can s post that when I get back if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating an interface file and call it "tinymceeditorupload.asp" and add it to the editor folder. Then you can call that file by adding this line to the tinymce.init() script like:

```
images_upload_url: 'editor/tinymceeditorupload.asp?Folder=myFoldername'
```

Then for tinymceeditorupload.asp use:

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="aspupload/asp_upload.asp"-->
<%
Dim strJSN
Dim fs
Dim Form: Set Form = New ASPForm
Dim strFolder
Dim strFolderPath
Dim strFileName

strFolder = Request.QueryString("Folder")

Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolderPath = Server.MapPath("docs") & "\" & strFolder

'***CHECK IF FOLDER EXISTS
If fs.FolderExists(strFolderPath) = False Then 
Set f=fs.CreateFolder(strFolderPath)
Set f=Nothing 
End If 
Set fs=Nothing 

If Form.State = 0 Then
For Each File In Form.Files.Items
strFileName = File.FileName
If Len(strFileName) > 0 Then
   Form.Files.Save strFolderPath 
End If
Next
strJSN = "{""location"":""https:\/\/example.com\/tinymce\/docs\/"&strFolder&\/"&strFileName&"""}"
Response.Write(strJSN)
End If 

%>
```

Comment: Sorry that it took so long to get back to you... I had lost this script because in my project I went with FKeditor for better all round browser support.

Comment: There was nothing to found anywhere about this method. Thank you for this!